# Username/Password not being verified

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to do a refresher with Java by making a simple Swing Login form, yesterday i had problems with it not being able to have an output at all and now i got it to working. Now the problem that im having is that either the username or password is not being verified since its displaying the else condition. Kindly check where i have gone wrong, and yes the database has the fields admin/admin for the userpass but still not being verified. Here's my code.

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(Username.getText().length()==0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up blank fields!");
    }
    else if(Password.getPassword().length==0 ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up blank fields!");
    }
    else {
        String user = Username.getText();
        char[] pass = Password.getPassword();
        String pwd = String.copyValueOf(pass);
        if(validate_login(user, pwd)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful!");
            System.exit(0);
                    }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username/Password");

        }
    }
}

 private boolean validate_login (String username, String password) {
    try {
        Class.forName(".com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306" + "user=root&password");
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=? and password=?");
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet RS = pst.executeQuery();
        if(RS.next()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Which `else` statement you are talking about? May be you are giving wrong credential or whatever query you fired its return nothing Check same query manually.

Comment: Did you try to run the sql manually on the database with your input and check the result?

Comment: have cross checked your log, are not you getting any exception?

Comment: @Subodhj Im talking about the ` else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username/Password");

        }`

Comment: @KevinEsche Hmm, not sure what you're asking me to do, sorry been too long without coding :(

Comment: @PiyushMittal No exceptions. Regarding the logs is that the error you get when you pushed the button? BTW im using NetBeans 8.0.2

Comment: yes right @KenDogcio

Comment: I just noticed that it does.. -.- 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
 at login.login.validate_login(login.java:150)
 at login.login.btnLoginActionPerformed(login.java:132)
 at login.login.access$000(login.java:15)
 at login.login$1.actionPerformed(login.java:52)

Comment: you need to put the mysql-jar in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Make changes into the `validate_login()` .

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName", Username, Password);
```

And you can also use the different type of the getConnection() method just like below.

```
getConnection(String url)

getConnection(String url, Properties prop)

getConnection(String url, String user, String password)
```

Comment: Since its an mySQL DB, should it be com.mysql.jdbc.Connection ?

Comment: no ken Dogcio. It is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Go through this site http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your DB configuration is correct, check below things,

1. Check if any encryption/decryption is required before executing the query.
2. Copy the query with the parameters, try to execute directly in database and see what result it yields.